# Mapbox custom layers not showing up using WebGL javascript library

Tags: mapbox

Good morning,

I modified one of the Mapbox GLJS coded examples with my custom data.
I am still not able to display the content of my layers.
It is supposed to update the chloropleth by zooming.
I received a lot of help from the customer support but to no avail so far.
I am not the most talented developer out there!

Here the link of the Mapbox example I used. 
(https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/updating-choropleth/)

Here also a JSfiddle link to the modified example.
(https://jsfiddle.net/2fe3emd6/28/)

The modified code is the following one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Update a choropleth layer by zoom level</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<style>

.legend {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    bottom: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.legend h4 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.legend div span {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 10px;
}

</style>

<div id='map'></div>

<div id='zoneveg-legend' class='legend' style='display: none;'>
    <h4>Zone de végétation</h4>
    <div><span style='background-color: #B8B2B2'></span>Zone arctique</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #539140'></span>Zone boréale</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #7FDA10'></span>Zone tempérée nordique</div>
</div>

<div id='dombio-legend' class='legend' style='display: none;'>
    <h4>Domaine bioclimatique</h4>
    <div><span style='background-color: #C3C4C1'></span>Toundra arctique herbacée</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #696C6C'></span>Toundra arctique arbustive</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #9A7BA1'></span>Toundra forestière</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #C48D99'></span>Pessière à lichens</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #A9ACCA'></span>Pessière à mousses</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #6895BC'></span>Sapinière à bouleau blanc</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #81BC84'></span>Sapinière à bouleau jaune</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #EFCE6D'></span>Érablière à bouleau jaune</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #B3AC7E'></span>Érablière à tilleul</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #E1779B'></span>Érablière à caryer cordiforme</div>
</div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2FtZiIsImEiOiJjaWZ3bGhtdjgzMnN1dWdrcnEwZTVieG91In0.DkCY-91coDahKvpH7Z26dw';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    center: [-72, 48],
    minZoom: 2,
    zoom: 3
});

var zoomThreshold = 4;

map.on('load', function() {

    map.addSource('zone', {
        'type': 'vector',
        'url': 'mapbox://thematix.dy544jx6'
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'NOM',
        'source': 'zone',
        'source-layer': 'zone_veg-9z9soa',
        'maxzoom': zoomThreshold,
        'type': 'fill',
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': [
            'match',
                ['get', 'NOM'],
                '', '#FFFFFF',
                'Boréale', '#539140',
                'Golfe du Saint-Laurent', '#90C4FF',
                'Zone articque', '#B8B2B2',
                'Tempérée nordique', '#7FDA10'
            ],
            'fill-opacity': 0.75
        }
    }, 'waterway-label');
    
    map.addSource('dom', {
        'type': 'vector',
        'url': 'mapbox://thematix.60h9x8bk'
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'NOM',
        'source': 'dom',
        'source-layer': 'dom_bio-9xc27o',
        'maxzoom': zoomThreshold,
        'type': 'fill',
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': [
            'match',
                ['get', 'NOM'],
                'Toundra arctique herbacée', '#C3C4C1',
                'Toundra arctique arbustive', '#696C6C',
                'Toundra forestière', '#9A7BA1',
                'Pessière à lichens', '#C48D99',
                'Pessière à mousses', '#A9ACCA',
                'Sapinière à bouleau blanc', '#6895BC',
                'Sapinière à bouleau jaune', '#81BC84',
                'Érablière à bouleau jaune', '#EFCE6D',
                'Érablière à tilleul', '#B3AC7E',
                'Érablière à caryer cordiforme', '#E1779B'   

            ],
            'fill-opacity': 0.75
        }
    }, 'waterway-label');
});

var zonevegLegendEl = document.getElementById('zoneveg-legend');
var dombioLegendEl = document.getElementById('dombio-legend');
map.on('zoom', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() > zoomThreshold) {
        zonevegLegendEl.style.display = 'none';
        dombioLegendEl.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        zonevegLegendEl.style.display = 'block';
        dombioLegendEl.style.display = 'none';
    }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanking you in advance.

Pierre-Y. Plourde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `match` expression you are using for both custom layers is missing the **default value** which is not optional.

Docs: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#expressions-match

Here is an updated jsfiddle which is using `rgba(0,0,0,0)` as default value for both `match` expressions.

https://jsfiddle.net/2fe3emd6/35/

E.g. for the layer with ID `ZONE_VEG` it looks like this:

```
 'fill-color': [
            'match',
                ['get', 'NOM'],
                '', '#FFFFFF',
                'Boréale', '#539140',
                'Golfe du Saint-Laurent', '#90C4FF',
                'Zone articque', '#B8B2B2',
                'Tempérée nordique', '#7FDA10',
                'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
            ],
```

You are of course free to use a different default value.

**Edit:**

The cause for the further issue mentioned in your comment (the first layer is hidden by the second layer) is that both layers are having the same zoom extend. To fix it, just change for the layer with ID `'DOM_BIO'` the  `'maxzoom'` to  `'minzoom'`.

Updated jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2fe3emd6/43/

Comment: Hello pathmapper, thanks a lot to share your expertise.

Comment: Hello pathmapper, it looks like my first comment was truncated. I noticed, when running the fiddle that the first ID ZONE_VEG shows briefly (less than a second) and then, the second ID DOM_BIO  appears over it, as it is now. If I removed the default rgba (0,0,0,0) setting from the match expression of the second ID, the first ID looks fine and synchronized with the color legend. Do you still have a magic trick for this? Many thanks.

Comment: @Pierre-YPlourde the first layer was hidden by the second layer, because both layers had the same zoom extend. Updated the answer to fix this.

Comment: Many thanks again pathmapper. I am facing another problem with a different example from Mapbox. Should I get in touch directly with you or create a new question on the forum?

Comment: @Pierre-YPlourde please create a new question